# Time stamp a cell when multiple columns are updated

Tags: spreadsheet

I have been checking out multiple codes on trying to update my Google Spreadsheet but have been unsuccessful when trying to do this with multiple cells. On my spreadsheet I have multiple tabs and when I update a row in column 2,3 or 4, I would like it to enter the date in column 5.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: You can mark the answer as "correct answer" if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1.

In the Google Spreadsheet, click on "Script editor..." under the "Tools" menu.

## Step 2.

Remove any sample script that might be in there and paste the following ...

```
// Sets the targetColumn on the edited row to the current date if the 
// edited column in within columnBounds.
// Note: This will only handle single cell editing.

// Columns that need to be monitored for changes. Use CAPITAL letters.
var monitoredColumns = ['B', 'C', 'D'];
// Colum that will receive the date.
var targetColumn = 'E'
// To avoid adding the date in the title row, we need to consider the starting row.
var startingRow = 4

// onEdit() is a reserved function name that will be called every time the sheet will be edited.
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;

  // Row of the edited cell.
  var row = range.getRow();

  // Column of the edited cell.
  var col = String.fromCharCode(64 + range.getColumn());

  if (row < startingRow) {
    // None of the monitored rows have been edited.
    return;
  }

  if (monitoredColumns.indexOf(col) < 0) {
    // Column B, C or D (2, 3 or 4) was not modified.
    // Do not proceed any further.
    return;
  }

  // Current spreadsheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Date cell.
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange(targetColumn + range.getRow());
  // Set it to the current date.
  dateCell.setValue(new Date());
}
```

## Step 3

Adjust the values of `monitoredColumns`, `targetColumn` and `startingRow`

## Step 4

Start entering some content in the cells.